# ASP.net fails to RegisterClientScriptBlock

Tags: c#, asp.net

When I try to register this script in my trace it says it is not registered Even though I exclaim its registration here:

```
Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.GetType(), "DrillThrough report " + (int) dr["ReportID"] + " script", vbs_script);
```

The scripts file name is `DrillThrough6-0.Function.BT.SS2005.ReportID42193.vbs` What could be going wrong. Plus if I run Internet explorer using developer tools(maybe just a coincidence, but it constantly happens only with developer tools on) it registers fine. And runs as its suppose to otherwise it doesn't run at all.

Code for Context:

```
SqlDataReader dr = PivotTableDB.GetReport(drillThroughReportID);
        Trace.Warn("Attempting to Read... ");
        if (dr.Read()) {
            Trace.Warn("Reading... ");
            Page.ClientScript.RegisterHiddenField("txt_DetailReportCubeName", (string) dr["CubeName"]);

            string path = (string) this.MapPath("~/DesktopModules/PivotTableNav/DrillThroughReportScripts/");
            string name = (string) dr["DisplayName_en"] + ".ReportID" + (int) dr["ReportID"] + ".vbs";
            string vbs_script = "";

            if (File.Exists(path + name)) {

                StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(path + name,System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding("iso-8859-1"));
                vbs_script = sr.ReadToEnd();
                vbs_script = vbs_script.Replace("Spreadsheet1","document.Form1.Spreadsheet1");
                vbs_script = vbs_script.Replace("for=document.Form1.Spreadsheet1","for=Spreadsheet1");
                sr.Close();
            }

            if (vbs_script != null) {
                Trace.Warn("vbscript", vbs_script);
                Trace.Warn("vbscript-path", (path + name));
                Trace.Warn("vbscriptExist", "File exist: " + File.Exists(path + name) + " BlockRegistered already: " + Page.ClientScript.IsClientScriptBlockRegistered("DrillThrough report " + (int)dr["ReportID"] + " script"));
                if (! Page.ClientScript.IsClientScriptBlockRegistered("DrillThrough report " + (int) dr["ReportID"] + " script"))
                    Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.GetType(), "DrillThrough report " + (int) dr["ReportID"] + " script", vbs_script);
            }
            Trace.Warn("Was vbscript Registered: " + Page.ClientScript.IsClientScriptBlockRegistered("DrillThrough report " + (int)dr["ReportID"] + " script"));

            Title.Text = LanguageUtils.ChooseOnLanguage(dr["DisplayName_en"].ToString(), dr["DisplayName_fr"].ToString());

        }
        else { Trace.Warn("Did not read the report since no data no rows: "); }
        dr.Close();
```

Comment: Is your code running on UpdatePanel partial postback?

Comment: If it works in debug mode but not deployed then the issue is file rights when deployed.  Set the file to have full rights for all uses and test again.  If that works then figure out what rights are correct (you don't want full rights on a script file.)

Comment: Hou you tried registering with another name? a Simple one like `RegisterScript`? Don't know if you are using some illegal cars there.

Comment: @Hogan I checked the file it has full permissions.

Comment: @VitorCanova I know my other registered scripts work fine and have simple names. I'll try that as the register name currently has a lot of periods in it now which may possibly be interferring

Comment: Make sure you have a`form runat="server"` on the page. I ran into this in the past and client scripts won't register without that for some reason. See here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.registerclientscriptblock(VS.71).aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get this to work i changed RegisterClientScriptBlock to RegisterStartupScript. And now the register is successful , obivious change isClientScriptBlockRegistered to the IsStartupScriptRegistered.